# Error copying buffer

Tags: c#, tcp

I have the following error `Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.` After a while my client is connected and sending packets to me. I am using this code as my network core: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod and I modified the `MessageHandler.cs` to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace PTEmu.NetworkCore
{
    class MessageHandler
    {

        public bool HandleMessage(SocketAsyncEventArgs receiveSendEventArgs, DataHoldingUserToken receiveSendToken, Int32 remainingBytesToProcess)
        {
            bool incomingTcpMessageIsReady = false;

            //Create the array where we'll store the complete message, 
            //if it has not been created on a previous receive op.
            if (receiveSendToken.receivedMessageBytesDoneCount == 0)
            {
                receiveSendToken.GetDataHolder().dataMessageReceived = new Byte[receiveSendToken.lengthOfCurrentIncomingMessage];
            }

            // Remember there is a receiveSendToken.receivedPrefixBytesDoneCount
            // variable, which allowed us to handle the prefix even when it
            // requires multiple receive ops. In the same way, we have a 
            // receiveSendToken.receivedMessageBytesDoneCount variable, which
            // helps us handle message data, whether it requires one receive
            // operation or many.
            if (remainingBytesToProcess + receiveSendToken.receivedMessageBytesDoneCount + 4 == receiveSendToken.lengthOfCurrentIncomingMessage)
            {
                // If we are inside this if-statement, then we got 
                // the end of the message. In other words,
                // the total number of bytes we received for this message matched the 
                // message length value that we got from the prefix.

                // Write/append the bytes received to the byte array in the 
                // DataHolder object that we are using to store our data.
                Buffer.BlockCopy(receiveSendEventArgs.Buffer, 
                    receiveSendToken.receiveMessageOffset - 4,  // I want the length of the packet in the final MessagePacket aswell
                    receiveSendToken.GetDataHolder().dataMessageReceived, 
                    receiveSendToken.receivedMessageBytesDoneCount, 
                    remainingBytesToProcess);

                incomingTcpMessageIsReady = true;
            }

            else
            {
                // If we are inside this else-statement, then that means that we
                // need another receive op. We still haven't got the whole message,
                // even though we have examined all the data that was received.
                // Not a problem. In SocketListener.ProcessReceive we will just call
                // StartReceive to do another receive op to receive more data.


                Buffer.BlockCopy(receiveSendEventArgs.Buffer, 
                    receiveSendToken.receiveMessageOffset,
                    receiveSendToken.GetDataHolder().dataMessageReceived, 
                    receiveSendToken.receivedMessageBytesDoneCount, 
                    remainingBytesToProcess); // THE ERROR IS HERE.

                receiveSendToken.receiveMessageOffset = receiveSendToken.receiveMessageOffset - receiveSendToken.recPrefixBytesDoneThisOp;

                receiveSendToken.receivedMessageBytesDoneCount += remainingBytesToProcess;
            }

            return incomingTcpMessageIsReady;
        }
    }
}
```

And I added some methods to get the variables inside `DataHoldingUserToken` :

```
public DataHolder GetDataHolder() { return theDataHolder; }
public Mediator GetMediator() { return theMediator; }
```

The error is in the `Buffer.BlockCopy` inside the else statement. If you need any more code just tell me, I don't know exactly where the error is, I'm not so good in tcp/ip.

Comment: What type are exception are you receiving? Are you running over one of your buffers?

Comment: `ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.` `receiveSendEventArgs.Buffer` is a byte[4136960], `receiveSendToken.receiveMessageOffset` is 4096004, `receiveSendToken.GetDataHolder().dataMessageReceived` is byte[32], `receiveSendToken.receivedMessageBytesDoneCount` is 0 and `remainingBytesToProcess` is 80. Thats all the info I could get from Visual Studio

Comment: I would also look at --> receiveSendToken.receiveMessageOffset - 4. You are copying 4 less bytes but not compensating for that in your offset variables.

Comment: How should I compensate?

Comment: Ah, you have receiveSendToken.receivedMessageBytesDoneCount + 4. I di not scroll far enough. My mistake.

Comment: Any other hints of what may be causing that problem?